# function for getting instance of class VS calling class directly

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#obtaining-a-desktop-widget

> The QApplication::desktop() function is used to get an instance of QDesktopWidget.

I don't understand why should you use `QApplication::desktop()`, when you can just directly call `QDesktopWidget()` class.
What is the difference between

```
desktop = QApplication.desktop()
```

and

```
desktop = QDesktopWidget()
```

They look like the same. But Windows(OS) throws warning on exit when using `QDesktopWidget()`. So there should be some difference.

How they differs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may look the same but are not. On the C++ side the static desktop() function is using a singleton pattern - there is only one desktop and it is represented by a static variable, which may (or may not) be created on request. QDesktopWidget() is a constructor, which is not accessible for the "outside world" to guarantee the uniqueness of the singleton.

Comment: QDesktopWidget's constructor is public.

Comment: I think hmuelner's answer is correct. Source code: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/kernel/qapplication.cpp#line3239

Comment: QDesktopWidget's constructor is indeed public (I did not check the sources before). But this is either an oversight or there is some technical reason (speak: HACK) for this. Its indented use is obviously as a singleton.